# Practical differences between explicitly subscribing to an Observable vs calling subscribe() with parameter

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a service that returns an Observable:

```
contactsSerice (): Observable<Contact[]> {...}
```

For using this data on my template and keep the template "alive" based on what's in the Observable I've found two ways.

I declared a `Subject` within the context of my Component:

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

    contacts$: Subject<Contact[]> = new Subject<Contact[]>();
    constructor(){}

}
```

And then:

1. Explicitly subscribing to the Observable (and emitting the contacts) like this:

```
ngOnInit() {

   this.contactsSerice().subscribe((contacts: Contact[]) => {
           this.contacts$.next(contacts);
   });
}
```

2. Calling directly the `.subscribe()` using my Subject as a parameter:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.contactsSerice().subscribe(this.contacts$);
}
```

After this, I can use the `| async` pipe in the template like:

```
<section *ngIf="contacts$ | async as contacts">
...
</section>
```

I was wondering if there's any practical difference between calling `subscribe()` passing the Subject vs properly subscribing to the Observable and trigger the Subject's `next()` method.

Comment: I think you don't need any of them. Just use `this.contacts$ = this.contactsSerice()` and then in templates `contacts$ | async`. Using an intermediate Subject is possible but has no practical benefit. You might complete the Subject independently on the Observable but that's I think very unlikely and would be just confusing.

Comment: Not really. If you do so then `contact$` has to be an `Observable` instead of a `Subject`. This will cause some "blinking" issues in the UI.

Comment: `Subject` is an `Observable` so you don't need any conversion. If you're seeing blinking then it looks like something is not triggering change detection. Can you make a demo on stackblitz where I could see how it's blinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an actual difference:

When we are subscribing via a `Subject` then `error` and `complete` notifications are passed to it. So if our source observable is completing, then the subject is completing as well. This might be an unwanted behaviour, because a completed `Subject` does ignore all further notifications.

```js
 /*
 Variant 1:
   This works only once:
     - The complete notification from the HTTP call is forwarded to the subscribing subject
     - A completed subject ignores further values
 */
 this.inventoryService.loadBeers(page).subscribe(this.beers$);


 // could be thought of the same as: 
 this.inventoryService.loadBeers()
   .subscribe(
     (response) => this.beers$.next(response), 
     (error) => this.beers$.error(error), 
     () => this.beers$.complete()
 );

 /*  
  Variant 2: Here we don't pass the completed event to the beers$ 
 */
 this.inventoryService.loadBeers()
   .subscribe(
     (response) => this.beers$.next(response), 
     (error) => console.log('Errors are not passed to beers$ subject'), 
     () => console.log('Complete notification is not passed to beers$ subject')
 );
```

You can also take a look at the [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-subi-http-calls-subject?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) where I tried to show this behaviour.

Comment: +1, meaning that if I follow the first variant, the next time I call `this.beers$.next(value)` the subscribers will not be "informed" about the new value.

Answer (score 0):

The short answers is none, there is no difference (besides that you will be using a bit more memory for the Subject itself).

From a practical point of view (let's say the question is when should I use intermediate Subject) you want to use intermediate subjects whenever you want to cache somehow the response that you receive from your back-end.

Let's say for example you want to do the following thing

```html
// Left side of the screen
<section *ngIf="contacts$ | async as contacts">
...
</section>

// Right side of the screen
<section *ngIf="contacts$ | async as contacts">
...
</section>
```

So in this case, if you are using directly the service you will make two calls to the back-end (as each `|async` is a new subscription).

So the short answer is that there will be no difference, but it is better to have it.

** Side note: If you are new to Angular and have trouble managing states, look into NGRX.